# Buy bitcoins using google checkout

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I want to buy a small amount of bitcoins using google checkout. Any service provider ?

Thanks

Comment: If Google Checkout is not a hard requirement, LocalBitcoins.com lists tons of payment methods https://localbitcoins.com/buy-bitcoins-online/usd/

Answer (score 2):

Not really.

[Buying Bitcoin Through Google Checkout](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=48498.0):

> Unsurprisingly, [neither] Apple nor Google will ever allow for digital currencies to be exchanged through their systems as a part of their TOS.

[btcnow.net](http://btcnow.net) used to, but apparently Google put the kibosh on that some time ago.

fireduck [asked in the Google Checkout/Wallet forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/checkout-merchant/RiIUWOo8sb8), but never really received an answer.

**HOWEVER**

[Bitcoin Keys](https://bitcoinkeys.wildapricot.org/) does digital delivery of private keys tied to accounts which have been loaded with the desired amount of BTC.

In my ~30 minutes of research on this, it's the only site I could find that does it in any way.

*I have not personally used any of these sites, so I cannot vouch for them.*

Answer (score 0):

Google Checkout does not allow their service to be used for the sale of virtual currencies.

See the [Google Checkout Program Policies and Guidelines](https://checkout.google.com/seller/policies.html).  Item 6 has a link to a page of [content policies](https://checkout.google.com/seller/content_policies.html) listing prohibited items.  (Somewhat confusingly, the latter page only mentions Google Wallet for Business and not Google Checkout.)  Under the "Financial" category, the list of prohibited items includes "transfers involving any virtual currency".